# Firebase Analytics in Xamarin Forms

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-analytics

Can we get custom events such as say Button 1 was pressed using Firebase Analytics in a Xamarin Forms Project ?

Answer (score 46):

> **Answer Updated for the new version of Xamarin Firebase components and to fix various issues**

Sure, you need to DI (dependency injection) to call the platform code.

- Configure your Firebase App: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more
- Reference the proper nuget packages for Firebase Analytics:

  **Android Project**

  - Xamarin.FireBase.Analytics
  - Xamarin.FireBase.Analytics.Impl
  - Plugin.CurrentActivity *(used to get the current context as* `Forms.Context` *is deprecated)*

    ---

  **iOS Project**

  - Xamarin.FireBase.iOS.Analytics (iOS project)

    ---
- In your PCL (or .NETStandard) project create the interface
- In the Android and iOS project write the plaftorm specific code
- In your viewmodels, use DI in the PCL (or .NETStandard) project to call the `LogEvent` method to store your event

> **Note:** Custom events are slow to appear in firebase, in my experience they need 24 hours to appear in the web console. If you
>   want to properly test the custom logging, use your phone and activate
>   the analytics debug (so you can see your events in the debugView in
>   firebase console)*

---

> **Note2:** watch out for the `eventId` property: names can be up to 40 characters long, may only contain alphanumeric characters and
>   underscores ("*"), and must start with an alphabetic character. The
>   "firebase*", "google_" and "ga_" prefixes are reserved and should not
>   be used. I have included a smal utility function to automatically fix
>   eventId, you can skip it if you want

---

## PCL or .NETStandard project

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MobileApp.Services
{
    public interface IAnalyticsService
    {
        void LogEvent(string eventId);
        void LogEvent(string eventId, string paramName, string value);
        void LogEvent(string eventId, IDictionary<string, string> parameters);
    }
}
```

## Android

> Make sure to have the INTERNET permission in your manifest.

Import your google-services.json (generated from your firebase account) with compilation action set to "GoogleServicesJson"

Remember to call `CrossCurrentActivity` init method in your AppDelegate `OnCreate`:

```
CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);
```

**This is the Android platform service code:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Android.OS;
using Firebase.Analytics;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
using MobileApp.Services;

namespace MobileApp.Droid.Services
{
    [assembly: Dependency (typeof(AnalyticsServiceDroid))]
    public class AnalyticsServiceDroid : IAnalyticsService
    {

        public void LogEvent(string eventId)
        {
            LogEvent(eventId, null);
        }

        public void LogEvent(string eventId, string paramName, string value)
        {
            LogEvent(eventId, new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {paramName, value}
            });
        }

        public void LogEvent(string eventId, IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {

            //utility method to fix eventId, you can skip it if you are sure to always pass valid eventIds
            eventId = FixEventId(eventId);

            var fireBaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext);

            if (parameters == null)
            {
                fireBaseAnalytics.LogEvent(eventId, null);
                return;
            }

            var bundle = new Bundle();

            foreach (var item in parameters)
            {
                bundle.PutString(item.Key, item.Value);
            }

            fireBaseAnalytics.LogEvent(eventId, bundle);
        }

        //utility method to fix eventId, you can skip it if you are sure to always pass valid eventIds
        private string FixEventId(string eventId)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eventId))
                return "unknown";

            //remove unwanted characters
            eventId = Regex.Replace(eventId, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+", "_", RegexOptions.Compiled);

            //trim to 40 if needed
            return eventId.Substring(0, Math.Min(40, eventId.Length));
        }

    }
}
```

**Debug View in Android**

To enable the debugView in the firebase run this command from your adb console command prompt (usually is `c:\WINDOWS\System32`, but you can reach it through Visual Studio in `tools --> android --> android adb command prompt`):

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <package_name>
```

To disable the debugView use:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.
```

**Verbose logging**

Verbose logging is usefyk to monitor logging of events by the SDK to help verify that events are being logged properly. This includes both automatically and manually logged events.

You can enable verbose logging with a series of adb commands:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

> **Important note**
>
> Some external libraries (Like MS AppCenter) are already including Firebase and explicitly disabling analytics in teir manifest.
>
> In these cases you need to modify your `AndroidManifest.xml` adding this line just before the `</application>` tag:
>
> ```
> <meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="false" tools:replace="android:value"/>
> ```
>
> Also make sure to have this property inside your `<manifest>` tag:
>
> ```
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> ```

## iOS

> **Make sure to test the event logging on your phone! This is not going to work anymore on emulators**

Initialize the component in your AppDelegate, just before base.FinishedLaunching:

```
Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
```

Then import your GoogleService-Info.plist (generated from your firebase account) with compilation action set to "BundleResource" .

**This is the iOS platform service code:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Firebase.Analytics;
using Firebase.Core;
using Foundation;
using MobileApp.Services;

namespace MobileApp.iOS.Services
{
    [assembly: Dependency (typeof(AnalyticsServiceIOS))]
    public class AnalyticsServiceIOS : IAnalyticsService
    {

        public void LogEvent(string eventId)
        {
            LogEvent(eventId, (IDictionary<string, string>)null);
        }

        public void LogEvent(string eventId, string paramName, string value)
        {
            LogEvent(eventId, new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { paramName, value }
            });
        }

        public void LogEvent(string eventId, IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {

            //utility method to fix eventId, you can skip it if you are sure to always pass valid eventIds
            eventId = FixEventId(eventId);

            if (parameters == null)
            {
                Analytics.LogEvent(eventId, parameters: null);
                return;
            }

            var keys = new List<NSString>();
            var values = new List<NSString>();
            foreach (var item in parameters)
            {
                keys.Add(new NSString(item.Key));
                values.Add(new NSString(item.Value));
            }

            var parametersDictionary =
                NSDictionary<NSString, NSObject>.FromObjectsAndKeys(values.ToArray(), keys.ToArray(), keys.Count);
            Analytics.LogEvent(eventId, parametersDictionary);

        }

        //utility method to fix eventId, you can skip it if you are sure to always pass valid eventIds
        private string FixEventId(string eventId)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eventId))
                return "unknown";

            //remove unwanted characters
            eventId = Regex.Replace(eventId, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+", "_", RegexOptions.Compiled);

            //trim to 40 if needed
            return eventId.Substring(0, Math.Min(40, eventId.Length));
        }
    }
}
```

**Debug View in iOS**

To enable the debugView in the firebase console add the following argument to Extra **mlaunch** Arguments in your iOS project properties:

```
--argument=-FIRDebugEnabled
```

To disable the debugView use:

```
--argument=-FIRDebugDisabled
```

> **Important note**
>   (*thanks to [Ken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56967324/9823528) for pointing out this*)
>
> If you get an exception calling `Firebase.Core.App.Configure();` in your AppDelegate, modify your `GoogleService-Info.plist` settings `IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED` to `true`

## In your ViewModel you can track any event you want

For Example:

```cs
public class MenuPageViewModel{
    public MenuPageViewModel(){
         var analyticsService= DependencyService.Get<IAnalyticsService>();
         //You can use any of the LogEvent Overloads, for example:
         analyticsService.LogEvent("Event");

    }
}
```

Comment: Firebase analytics is bad for xamarin crash analytics. It's better to use microsoft appcenter. https://appcenter.ms/

Comment: i'm using it for tracking analytical data (page views, user engagement, custom events, time on screens, ecc...). Last time i checked, appcenter was waaay behind Firebase regarding the analytics part. I think i'll need to re-check it!
Maybe you are speaking about Firebase Crashlytics? This is another topic. Firebase Crash Reporting has been discountinued and retired months ago.

Comment: @GiampaoloGabba  analyticsService.LogEvent("EventId","EventValue"); throwing System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error

Comment: @Shanmugasundharam the example code was wrong, the interface does not provide an overload with 2 strings. i have updated the answer. Also make sure to register the platform services with the DI container

Comment: @GiampaoloGabba  thanks for the update,  I have also updated my code and its got working fine, but  unable to read the data from my events. i guess  big query will provide the raw data.

Comment: @GiampaoloGabba. Thank you!  On Visual Studio 2019 for Mac, You access to Adb shell by clicking on menu :Tools/SDK Command prompt

Answer (score 1):

I followed this guideline with success.
I have one minor useful comment though: In the file `GoogleService-Info.plist`, I had to set `IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED` to true. Otherwise, I got en exception when calling `Firebase.Core.App.Configure();`

Answer (score 0):

your android service file is erroneous

Your code below

```
var bundle = new Bundle();

foreach (var item in parameters)
{
    bundle.PutString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ItemId, item.Key);
    bundle.PutString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ItemName, item.Value);
}
```

must be replaced with the following to track all parameters:

```
var bundle = new Bundle();

foreach (var item in parameters)
{
    bundle.PutString(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My code was for "suggested" firebase events but was working even for the custom ones. However, your is better :) Answer updated!