# Xamarin.Forms Firebase Analytics for iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, google-analytics, xamarin.ios, firebase-analytics

I am adding Firebase analytics to my Xamarin Forms app on iOS, currently following DI(Dependency Injection) for Firebase Analytics. Referring to this ([Firebase Analytics in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774378/firebase-analytics-in-xamarin-forms/50764452#50764452)). I am stuck at this error and don't know how to solve it. Following the error from my console:

```
5.8.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID017000] Could not determine the app's default Keychain access group (-34018)
2018-11-19 11:04:01.876059+0530 Sample.iOS[9231:68774] 5.8.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID009001] Error removing keypair status: -34018
2018-11-19 11:04:01.876563+0530 Sample.iOS[9231:68774] 5.8.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID010007] Unable to remove RSA keypair
2018-11-19 11:04:01.877675+0530 Sample.iOS[9231:68779] 5.8.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID009001] Error removing keypair status: -34018
Thread started:  #7
2018-11-19 11:04:02.083179+0530 Sample.iOS[9231:68779] 5.8.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID009001] Error removing keypair status: -34018
2018-11-19 11:04:02.083534+0530 Sample.iOS[9231:68779] 5.8.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID010007] Unable to remove RSA keypair
2018-11-19 11:04:02.087625+0530 Sample.iOS[9231:68779] 5.8.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID009001] Error removing keypair status: -34018
Thread started:  #8
2018-11-19 11:04:03.686673+0530 Sample.iOS[9231:68772] 5.8.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID010003] Unable to generate keypair.
2018-11-19 11:04:03.686932+0530 Sample.iOS[9231:68772] 5.8.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID010009] Keypair could not be loaded from Keychain. Error: Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=-34018 "(null)"
2018-11-19 11:04:03.687068+0530 Sample.iOS[9231:68772] 5.8.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS020001] Failed to get InstanceID: Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=-34018 "(null)"
2018-11-19 11:04:20.217396+0530 Sample.iOS[9231:68779] 5.8.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID009001] Error removing keypair status: -34018
2018-11-19 11:04:20.217547+0530 Sample.iOS[9231:68779] 5.8.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID010007] Unable to remove RSA keypair
2018-11-19 11:04:20.218886+0530 Sample.iOS[9231:68779] 5.8.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID009001] Error removing keypair status: -34018
```

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Is this help?https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1800. Try to update your IDE version and test on a real device.

Comment: Have you enabled the KeyChain in your Entitlement.plist? If yes, try to disable it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check the app in your phisical device, Firebase analytics are not going to work in the iOS emulators.

Meanwhile i have updated the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50764452/9823528 with a lot more informations and code fixes