# I am not able to configure firebase analytics to xamarin android project

Tags: xamarin.android, firebase-analytics

I am not able to integrate `firebase Analysis` to my `Xamarin` android project any help would be great. Thanks

I tried with adding NuGet packages below:

- `Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics.Impl`
- `Xamarin.Firebase.Common`
- `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement`

`Oncreate` in view:

```
protected override void OnCreate() 
{ 
  firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(this);? 
}

//setUI:I bundled the log events.
void SetUI()
{ 

 firebaseAnalytics.SetUserId(AppData.GlobalAppData.UserId); 
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
 bundle.PutString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ItemId, "1"); 
 bundle.PutString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ItemName, "adca"); 
 firebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(FirebaseAnal
}
```

Can someone provide with there experience and provide a solution for what all steps need to be taken.

Comment: Your post/question is very unclear. Please take some time to read it over and edit appropriately, using the formatting tools provided by the editor.

Comment: Check the answer in this thread:[firebase-analytics-in-xamarin-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774378/firebase-analytics-in-xamarin-forms)